# Excel Formula to check if two strings exist in the same row on a sheet without specifying the column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i'm trying to find out if there is a way to determine if two strings are in the same row somewhere on a sheet.

Right now i'm half way there, my not so elegant solution is just to count if a string exists in a sheet.

Excel Formula:

```
=COUNTIF('Sheet2'!3:100,Sheet1!B5)
```

This formula checks Sheet 2 row 3:100 if the value of B5 in Sheet 1 exists.

Excel Formula:

```
=IFERROR(ROW(INDEX(Sheet2!E:E,MATCH(1,("String1"=Sheet2!E:E)*("String2"=Sheet2!H:H)*("String3)"=Sheet2!A:A),0))),"9999")
```

This formula will return the row number the criteria are all found on, if not found, return 9999. The only issue with this is I have to specify the column on where the strings will be. Occasionally the columns move around.

My ideal formula: Find two criteria which are in the same row, without specifying the column, and then return the row number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will go row by row testing each string if in the whole row, then filter out the falses and join the trues:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(ROW(3:100),BYROW('Sheet2'!3:100,LAMBDA(Z,ISNUMBER(MATCH("String1",Z,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH("String2",Z,0)))))
```